# When will a StopIteration be converted into RuntimeError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, generator, stopiteration

I'm reading the documentation for Python 3 [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration):

> If a generator code directly or indirectly raises `StopIteration`, it is converted into a `RuntimeError` (retaining the `StopIteration` as the new exception's cause).

I don't understand that, can anyone explain?

This is what I've tried in Python 3.6, but nothing seems to have been caught:

```
def gen1():
    yield from [1, 2, 3]
    raise StopIteration

def gen2():
    raise StopIteration

try:
    a = list(gen1())
    # a == [1, 2, 3]
except RuntimeError:
    print("Caught")

try:
    a = gen1()
    next(a), next(a), next(a), next(a), next(a)
except RuntimeError:
    print("Caught")

try:
    gen2()
except RuntimeError:
    print("Caught")

try:
    a = list(gen2())
except RuntimeError:
    print("Caught")
```

Specially, both calls to `gen2()` raised the `StopIteration`, but still not converted into `RuntimeError`.

Comment: Note: `gen2` is *not a generator*. It is a regular function, and the PEP 479 changes do not apply to it. Add a `yield` expression to make it a generator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You missed that this change applies to Python 3.7 and newer. *You won't see the conversion in Python 3.6 or older*, unless you enable the feature with a `from __future__` import first (available as of Python 3.5).

From the same page you linked:

> *Changed in version 3.5*: Introduced the `RuntimeError` transformation via `from __future__ import generator_stop`, see PEP 479.
>
> *Changed in version 3.7*: Enable PEP 479 for all code by default: a `StopIteration` error raised in a generator is transformed into a `RuntimeError`.

[PEP 479 -- *Change StopIteration handling inside generators*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/) further details why this change was made and how it applies. For your code, running on Python 3.7, the output becomes:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> def gen1():
...     yield from [1, 2, 3]
...     raise StopIteration
...
>>> def gen2():
...     yield 42  # make this an actual generator
...     raise StopIteration
...
>>> try:
...     a = list(gen1())
... except RuntimeError:
...     print("Caught")
...
Caught
>>> try:
...     a = gen1()
...     next(a), next(a), next(a), next(a), next(a)
... except RuntimeError:
...     print("Caught")
...
Caught
>>> try:
...     a = list(gen2())
... except RuntimeError:
...     print("Caught")
...
Caught
```

Note that I added a `yield 42` line to `gen2()` to make it a generator. Without `yield` or `yield from` in the body, you get a regular function instead. Calling a generator function produces a generator object and the function body starts out paused, while calling a normal function executes the body immediately:

```
>>> def normal():
...     raise StopIteration
...
>>> def generator():
...     raise StopIteration
...     yield  # never reached, but this is now a generator
...
>>> normal()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in normal
StopIteration
>>> generator()
<generator object generator at 0x105831ed0>
>>> next(generator())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in generator
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

For Python 3.6, you'd use the `from __future__ import generator_stop` compiler switch (use it at the top of your code when writing a script or module):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> def generator():
...     raise StopIteration
...     yield
...
>>> next(generator())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in generator
StopIteration
>>> from __future__ import generator_stop
>>> def generator():  # re-define it so it is compiled anew
...     raise StopIteration
...     yield
...
>>> next(generator())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in generator
StopIteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```